# Can I use DRIMseq to model interaction effect of variables?

Tags: differential-expression

I am trying to use DRIMseq for DTU with 2 treatments on two different strains of mice. In my previous analysis with genes only, I had found a strong interaction effect  of strain and treatments. Is it possible to model that with DRIMseq?

Also when I try to add strain term and use it as the batch effect as described in the tutorial, I get the following error:

```
! Using a subset of 0.1 genes to estimate common precision !
Error in optimHess(par = par, fn = dm_lik_regG, gr = dm_score_regG, x = x,  : 
  non-finite value supplied by optim
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Please see the sessionInfo() below.

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] DRIMSeq_1.6.0                            pheatmap_1.0.8                           ggplot2_2.2.1                           
 [4] edgeR_3.16.5                             limma_3.30.13                            TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.knownGene_3.4.0
 [7] GenomicFeatures_1.26.4                   AnnotationDbi_1.36.2                     Biobase_2.34.0                          
[10] GenomicRanges_1.26.4                     GenomeInfoDb_1.10.3                      IRanges_2.8.2                           
[13] S4Vectors_0.12.2                         BiocGenerics_0.20.0                      tximport_1.2.0                          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.12               RColorBrewer_1.1-2         plyr_1.8.4                 pillar_1.2.1               compiler_3.4.0            
 [6] XVector_0.14.1             bitops_1.0-6               tools_3.4.0                zlibbioc_1.20.0            biomaRt_2.30.0            
[11] digest_0.6.12              bit_1.1-12                 gtable_0.2.0               RSQLite_2.0                memoise_1.1.0             
[16] tibble_1.4.2               lattice_0.20-35            pkgconfig_2.0.1            rlang_0.2.0                Matrix_1.2-10             
[21] DBI_0.7                    stringr_1.3.0              rtracklayer_1.34.2         Biostrings_2.42.1          locfit_1.5-9.1            
[26] bit64_0.9-7                grid_3.4.0                 XML_3.98-1.10              BiocParallel_1.8.2         magrittr_1.5              
[31] reshape2_1.4.3             blob_1.1.0                 MASS_7.3-47                scales_0.5.0               Rsamtools_1.26.2          
[36] GenomicAlignments_1.10.1   SummarizedExperiment_1.4.0 colorspace_1.3-2           labeling_0.3               stringi_1.1.7             
[41] lazyeval_0.2.1             munsell_0.4.3              RCurl_1.95-4.10
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to see the interaction effect would be including it in the design matrix as explained in the [limma tutorial](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/limma/inst/doc/usersguide.pdf). Something on the line of:

```
design_full <- model.matrix(~ treatment*strain, data = samples(d))
```

Or you could build it yourself in a matrix like

```
 (Intercept) strainA_treatmentA strainA_treatmentB  strainB_treatmentA strainB_treatmentB
       1                      0                  1                  0                   0
       1                      1                  0                  0                   0
```

About the error, it seems like the data is not in the right format, you have either `NA` or `Inf` somewhere in the matrix. Check it and rethink the processing you made.